# How to set default path with playbooks for ansible?

Tags: ansible

I've started use ansible for configuring my VM's. But for an applied playbook, I using the full path for it. How can I set default playbooks path for ansible?

Comment: `ansible-playbook` uses current directory as search path as most of other tools do. What is your use case?

Comment: I have playbooks in directory `/home/foo/playbook`. If I in any other directroy and put `ansible-playbook bar.yml` ansible found `bar.yml` in `/home/foo/playbook` and applied it.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an ansible question, more like bash.

You may add alias to your `.bash_profile` like this:

```
alias ansible-pb=anspb
anspb() {
  ANS_DIR=/home/foo/playbook;
  echo "Changing to $ANS_DIR and executing: ansible-playbook $@"
  (cd $ANS_DIR; ansible-playbook $@)
}
```

Then just call `ansible-pb bar.yml` to call a subshell, that changes to the `ANS_DIR` directory and pass all arguments to `ansible-playbook`.

Comment: But that change the current directory. I don't want to change it. But if storing `pwd` command output and go to back after executing `ansible-playbook` it may be work fine.

Comment: @Tutunak no, this uses subshell, so `cd` doesn't change the directory of your current shell